# terminal GNOME lost scroll, how to back normal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am using UBUNTU 16 LTS and terminal GNOME v3.18... How to back to standard configuration?

I try to use mouse scroll and pgUp/pgDwn but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a program switched to the *alternate screen* without restoring.  This will undo that (a command):

```
tput rmcup
```